# largest diameter car maneuverable

Tags: c, algorithm

Question:

A number of traffic cones have been placed on a circular racetrack to form an obstacle course. You are asked to determine the largest sized car that can navigate the course. For simplicity, the cones are assumed to have zero width and the car is perfectly circular and infinitely maneuverable. The track itself is the area between 2 concentric circles.

Formally, the course can be navigated by a car of radius c if there exists a closed loop around the center of the track which lies between the circles forming the track, and every point on the loop is at least c distance away from each cone and each boundary of the track.

My Approach:

Find distance between every pair of points and then for each point in the set find the closest point to it in the same set. Let this distance be `dist[i]` for ith point and compare `dist[i]` with the `max((inner_radius-dist),(outer_radius-dist))` and which ever is less is the radius of the car.

I coded this logic and I am getting wrong answer. I am not sure if my algorithm is correct. Can someone please verify or suggest a better algorithm.

[EDIT] The following is the code in <strike>`c++`</strike> `c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TEST_SIZE 500

/* This code is plain C so no need for this line:
using namespace std; */

int main(void) {
    int testCases, n;
    float x[TEST_SIZE], y[TEST_SIZE];//x[i], y[i] constitute pair (x,y) for ith point
    float distance, dist, min, r, R,radius;
    scanf("%d", &testCases);
    while ( testCases-- ) {
        scanf("%f%f%d", &r,&R, &n);
        //printf("r: %f, R: %f, n: %d\n", r, R, n);
        for (int i=0; i<n ; i++) {
            scanf("%f%f", &x[i], &y[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
                if (j!=i) {
                    dist = ((x[i]-x[j])*(x[i]-x[j])) + ((y[i]-y[j])*(y[i]-y[j]));// rhs of this equation is square of distance between 2 points
                    if(j==0 || dist>min) {
                        min=dist;
                    }
                //  printf("dist: %f\n", dist);
                }
            }
            min=sqrt(min);
            radius=sqrt((x[i]*x[i]) + (y[i]*y[i]));
            if(radius-r > R-radius) {
                if(min>radius-r) {
                min=radius-r;
                }
            } else {
                if(min>R-radius) {
                    min=R-radius;
                }
            }
            if(i==0 || distance>min) { 
                distance = min;
            }
        }
                    distance = floorf(distance*1000 + .5)/1000;
        //printf("distance: %f\n", distance);
        printf ("%f\n", distance);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might get closed as it's more a maths/geometry question than software development:(

Comment: Well not much of geometry is involved except Pythagoras theorem, I think it is more of algorithms question

Comment: Also, 'dist = ((x[i]-x[j])*(x[i]-x[j])) + ((y[i]-y[j])*(y[i]-y[j]))'.  Single-letter var names and over-complex one-line expressions don't help anyone much.  What is 'wrong answer'?  What is 'right answer?  Have you thought about a debugging strategy? Have you considered splitting up those complex arithmetic expressions by adding in some usefully-named temporary vars?

Comment: I have added a few comments. Hope it makes things clear

Comment: That's some cool car you have there.

Comment: Why are you searching for `min`, and then go on using temporary `dist`? Proper coding would have helped a *lot* here. Why is `dist` and every other variable "global" within the function?

Comment: Sorry to say this, but I think you are simply not putting enough effort in this assignment, and jumping to SO for help way too quickly. Adding even the most basic `printf` to trace the core of the algorithm should have shown the error I mentioned.

Comment: @mvds `dist` stores the square of distance between the ith and jth point while `min` is the minimum square of distance found till now for the ith point. As for variables they are global to save time on re-declaration that will happen each time loop is run(testCases can be around 1000), though compiler may do these optimization but I can also code them.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam oh please, don't try to out-smart the compiler... Again, what do you *do* with `min` after you have found it? *nothing!* Your "optimization" has led to a blatant bug: `dist` should be local to the inner loop, `min` should be the only result from the loop. Now you're just taking the last value of `dist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is not correct. Consider a test case with just two cones that are extremely close to each other (their distance is nearly 0). Your algorithm will wrongly compute the diameter to be the distance between these points. However the real diameter could close to the width of the circular track. You have to consider the global structure of the points to solve this problem.

EDIT: Any track taken by the car partitions the points and the circles into two sets: those appearing on the left and those appearing on the right. Note that the inner circle is always on the left side and the outer is always on the right. Let the distance between two sets is the minimum distance between any two points belonging to them. Then you have to find a partition of these points (in which the left and right circle belong to different parts) that maximizes the distance between it's two parts. Such a partition can be obtained by computing a minimum spanning tree of the points and the circles and finding the maximum edge that separates the left circle from the right circle in the tree.